# On Click Dissapear html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why is it that when I click on the button the status refreshes, but the button dissappears?

JS

```
$( ".refreshstatus" ).click(function(){
    $( ".navplayers" ).load('stats.php');
});
```

CSS

```
.refreshstatus{
    font-family:'Noto Sans';
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:tomato;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="refreshstatus">Refresh</div>
```

stats.php

```
    <?php include ("statsfunction.php"); ?><?php if( ( $Players = $Query->GetPlayers( ) ) !== false ): foreach( $Players as $Player ): ?>                                           
        <img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $Player ); ?>/32"><div class="playerinfo" id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $Player ); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $Player ); ?></div></img>                                                                  
    <?php endforeach; else: ?>
    No players
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p><b>Players <?php echo "<font color='green' ><?php $players_online ?></font>"  ?> online</b></p>
<div class="col-sm-3 navplayers">
<?php include ("stats.php"); ?>
<div class="refreshstatus">Refresh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the button is inside the status element ?

Comment: Is refreshstatus inside navplayers

Comment: @misterManSam - but I'm damn close to getting it right, any day now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your `div.refreshstatus` is being overlapped by your loaded content. Make a proper button or use an `<a>` link.

Something like...

```
<div class="col-sm-3 navplayers">
<?php include ("stats.php"); ?>
    <a href="#" class="refreshstatus">Refresh</a>
</div>
```

Or a button...

```
<div class="col-sm-3 navplayers">
<?php include ("stats.php"); ?>
    <button type="button" class="refreshstatus">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

Comment: heh, i figured it out my self ! i just needed to put div.navplayers in a seperate div like this :

  `code`  <div class="col-sm-3">
     <div class="navplayers">
    <?php include ("stats.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="refreshstatus">Refresh</div>
    </div>

Comment: That will work, but it is best to use an `<a>` or `<button>`... especially if you want this to work across browsers particularly older browsers which will not work well with a clickable `<div>`. Highly recommended!